# How should I speed up the writing speed of pickle.dump()

Tags: python, pickle

Currently, I want to save the generated array of objects as a file. I use the pickle.dump() method as follows:

```
    if mode == 'local' or mode == 'hpc':
        graph = toolbox.init_regular_network()
        all_record_list = simulation.run_simulation_show_all_process(
            graph, single_iterator_list,
            list_name.split('_')[0])
        if mode == 'hpc':
            f = open('result\Record_list', 'wb')
            pickle.dump(all_record_list, f)
```

Since my object array is very large, the generated files are >4G, and it takes a long time to write, how should I optimize it?
Looking forward to your help！

Comment: `cpickle` maybe? https://pymotw.com/3/pickle/

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the protocol to the highest possible.

```
pickle.dump(all_record_list, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

From the docs:

> Changed in version 3.0: The default protocol is 3.
>
> Changed in version 3.8: The default protocol is 4.
>
> ...
>
> •  Protocol version 0 is the original “human-readable” protocol and is backwards compatible with earlier versions of Python.
>
> •  Protocol version 1 is an old binary format which is also compatible with earlier versions of Python.
>
> •  Protocol version 2 was introduced in Python 2.3. It provides much more efficient pickling of new-style classes. Refer to PEP 307 for information about improvements brought by protocol 2.
>
> •  Protocol version 3 was added in Python 3.0. It has explicit support for bytes objects and cannot be unpickled by Python 2.x. This was the default protocol in Python 3.0–3.7.
>
> •  Protocol version 4 was added in Python 3.4. It adds support for very large objects, pickling more kinds of objects, and some data format optimizations. It is the default protocol starting with Python 3.8. Refer to PEP 3154 for information about improvements brought by protocol 4.
>
> •  Protocol version 5 was added in Python 3.8. It adds support for out-of-band data and speedup for in-band data. Refer to PEP 574 for information about improvements brought by protocol 5.

Docs can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html